# javascript pass data from parent to iframe

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe

how can i pass my data to iframe? some solution i found on the internet uses form having the iframe as it's target, but it is not applicable on my case. I need to pass large javascript variable to a form in iframe.

Comment: Is the frame hosted on the same domain as your page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
    parent.your_var

Answer (score 0):

```
contentWindow.parent.myVariable
```